# How to pass data from one process to another with WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have two processes (Authenticator.exe, and testProg.exe), I'd like for the testProgram to send a 32bit int to the Authenticator, who would then reply with a string.

I'm not super familiar with WCF, my experience goes no further then emulating the tutorial I'd found here: https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/

but I'm not sure how to have testProg send a value to Authenticator and "wait" for a response, nor am I familiar with how Authenticator can wait on receiving a sent message, and then extract data for use from it.

Any help or direction to answers would be lovely

Comment: To make clear, I essentially want to send an int from testProg to Authenticator, have Authenticator do some simple math (int=int*2 or something), and then have Authenticator return the result to testProg to be verified. This is just a simple test app for now, I'm working out different features for my later program

Comment: "*how Authenticator can wait on receiving a sent message*" This question is too broad, i mean WCF does this stuff out of the box, a wcf service will wait for a message, thats its job in life, and a client will wait for a response unless you set it up otherwise

Comment: I don't think you are at the stage of asking questions about this topic, i feel you are at the research and investigation phase, you need to make some examples, read the documentations and blogs, try some things out....

Comment: @TheGeneral none of the examples I come across give a very good example of what I want to achieve, only sample of setting up WCF (as seen in linked example from question), or things much more complex then my current education or needs

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for Duplex Services in the WCF. This contract allows the server to send the message back to the client as the client provides a channel to do that when connecting to the server.

Here is the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services